# "Class type" of "type parameter" used by generic java function

Tags: java, templates, generics, inheritance

I have written the following generic function in Java:

```
public <T extends MyClass> void loadProperties(String in_strPath)
{
   // ...
}
```

The type T can be any of 3 different classes which are children of MyClass. Let's call those 3 classes MyClassV1, MyClassV2 and MyClassV3. I would like to print the name of the class that corresponds to T from whithin loadProperties. I tried doing this:

```
Class<T> c = T.class;
T instance = c.newInstace();
System.out.println(instance.getClass().getName());
```

But it does not work. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: The first line says "Cannot select from a type variable".

Comment: Assuming this could work (it can't), why would you construct a new instance just to get the same `Class` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` represents type parameter, which gets "type-erased", so neither `newInstance` nor `getClass().getName()` would produce the desired result.

There is an idiom that you need to follow in order to make this work - pass `Class<T>` as a regular parameter to your method.

```
public <T extends MyClass> void loadProperties(String in_strPath, Class<T> classArg) {
    ...
    T instance = classArg.newInstance();
    System.out.println(instance.getClass().getName());
}
```

The caller needs to pass `MyClassV1.class`, `MyClassV2.class`, or `MyClassV3.class` as the second parameter.

Now that you use `classArg` instead of `T`, the code works as expected.

Comment: `newInstace()` won't compile.

Comment: @LewBloch Thanks! When you see an obvious typo like that, feel free to edit the answer.